# как в Tableviewcell сделать чтоб при добавлении новой ячейки она в вверх добавлялась?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Ребята такая ситуация , подскажите как сделать чтоб при добавлении новой  ячейки она вверх загружалась при Parse. Загружаю данные они все идут вниз не по очередности.

Comment: Попробую угадать, Вы добавляете элемент в массив `array.append(element)`?

Comment: Типа того, но вы не правильный под предлагаете , я вижу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourArray.insert(element, at: 0)     
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Ответ от [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870206/how-to-insert-new-cell-into-uitableview-in-swift).